# Increasing the searching speed of Django set.all()

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to filter through a MongoDB full of data. Right now I have code that is working and have found where my slowdown is at...

```
def does_this_property_apply(prop, app, dev, event):

    for platform_device in prop.platformdevice_set.all():
        for event in platform_device.applicable_events.all():
            if event.name == event:
                for app in platform_device.applicable_app.all():
                    if app.name == app:
                        for device in platform_device.applicable_device.all():
                            if device.name == dev:
                                print("This property applies")
```

Basically I have 400+ properties that have a bunch of metadata. Inside of each property is a `platform_device` object (model) that contains information such as `app`, `dev`, and `event`. Think of it as this property only applies to certain applications, on certain devices, on certain user actions (events). Each property can have multiple of these.

I am new to Django and trying to find out how I could quickly search all `platform_device` in the database and find if this property (prop) is applicable to my event, device, and application.

```
class PlatformDevice(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = 'Property Specifics'

    property_field = models.ForeignKey('Property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    applicable_app = models.ArrayReferenceField(to=Platform, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    applicable_device = models.ArrayReferenceField(to=Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    applicable_events = models.ArrayReferenceField(to=Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    event_group = models.ArrayReferenceField(to=EventGroups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```